# Blank screen on my domain and automatic Zip download

Tags: php, mysql, screen

when i try upload something on my domain ftp, blank screen appiers and automatic Zip download starts , even phpinfo not working. I have dedicated server and never had any problems

My domain is  and i want to install script at http://fablefly.com/install

Can You look Guys ?

P.S i'm running Cpanel , php 5.2 , mysql , ion cube enabled.

Comment: How can a blank screen appear, when you try to upload by ftp? This is definitely a lie.

Comment: what are you uploading? looks like you have your content type messed up. it is your page which is sent as zip content type.

Comment: sorry, after upload and accessing domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you mean. I had the issue before when I set up my server and installed PHP, whenever I went to a page, it downloaded a useless file. I solved the issue by running the following commands via ssh.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Not sure exactly how you would go about doing this via cpanel as I use webmin personally and do most of the work via command line. But I believe this is your issue.

See this page 
http://serverkb.co.uk/wiki/PHP - the section titled "PHP Page downloading"

Check this out
http://cpanelhostingstuff.com/php-files-are-downloading-instead-of-executing/

Also look at some of these pages https://www.google.co.uk/#q=php+downloading+instead+of+executing+cpanel